# jQuery - Animate numbers when appears in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, viewport

I'm currently trying to **animate some numbers when the user scroll and the DIV appears in the viewport.** Like that: http://www.dimfolio.fr/

On the example it looks to be CSS3, for some reasons **I'd prefer to use jQuery.**

Currently, I use "[animateNumber](https://github.com/aishek/jquery-animateNumber)" plugin and this function to check if the div appears in the viewport:

```
$.fn.is_on_screen = function(){

var win = $(window);

var viewport = {
    top : win.scrollTop(),
    left : win.scrollLeft()
};
viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

var bounds = this.offset();
bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};
```

Here is my code:

**JS:**

```
function animate_stats() {
  $('.stats_number').each(function() {
     if(!$(this).hasClass("numbered")) {
        var thisnumber = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).animateNumber({ number: thisnumber }, 3000, function() {
            $(this).addClass('numbered');
        });
     }
  });
};

if( $('#statistics').is_on_screen() ) {
  animate_stats();
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if( $('#statistics').is_on_screen() ) {
     animate_stats();
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="stat">
   <div class="stats_number" title="79">0</div>
   <br />
   My title
</a>
```

The problem is that the number animation repeats and repeats again when the div appears. Of course **I'd like the animation to run only once.**

I suppose that the issue comes from my utilisation of "each" function but note sure.

Anyone can help? Thank you very much!

Comment: might want to check out [WOW.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, anyway as I said I'd prefer to use jQuery instead of CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the animation is run, remove the listener.

```
$(window).on('scroll.animateStats', function(){
  if( $('#statistics').is_on_screen() ) {
     animate_stats();
     $(window).off('scroll.animateStats');
  }
});
```

I namespaced the scroll event so that when we remove it we're only removing this event handler, and not *all* scroll handlers.